# Check if element wise condition in Scala list

Tags: scala

I would like to get a list such as

```
val mask = List(true, false, false, false, false)
```

when evaluating elementwise if an element is equal to "DoubleType"

```
val column_type = List("DoubleType", "LongType", "LongType", "LongType", "StringType")
```

I got something similar when using

```
val mask = new ListBuffer[String]()

for (name <- column_type)
    mask += (name == "DoubleType").toString
```

But you can see that I had to turn every element into a string, otherwise I get an error. And this way I can't use it later as a mask.
What should I do? Any more scalastic way of solving this issue?

Comment: If you create a listbuffer of strings, then you have to save strings. If you want to save doubles then create a list buffer of doubles... and you do not need mutability for something that trivial. It would be good to make any Scala 101 tutorial.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the `map(...)` method on `List`. It allows mapping each element to something else and you will receive a new list with the mapped elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map` with a predicate

```
val mask = column_type.map(_ == "DoubleType")
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way to accomplish your goal is via `map`:

```
scala> val mask = column_type.map(_ == "DoubleType")
mask: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, false, false, false)
```

Scala has a rich suite of tools for operating on collections, see https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/collections-methods.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
val mask=column_type.map(a=>a.equals("DoubleType"))
```

Comment: You do not need, nor you should call the `equals` method directly in **Scala**.